# @function in CoffeeScript does not work as advertised

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Rails 3.2.8. In converting some of my JS functions over to CoffeeScript, I have come across several questions that say declaring a function like so:

```
@foo = (bar) ->
```

puts `foo` in the global namespace. But it doesn't, because my function calls elsewhere in the application, especially ones that are in `.js.erb` files.

Here's what does work:

```
foo = (bar) ->

window.foo = foo
```

With that, all my calls in `.js.erb` files work fine.

What is the reason that the `@foo =` notation doesn't work as I am expecting it to? That would be a lot easier than having to remember to add an extra line to expose the function to the global namespace.

Comment: where do you get that `@foo` puts foo in the global namespace?

Comment: `@` is not a syntax to add things to the global namespace, it's just a shorthand for `this` or `this.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@foo` translates to `this.foo`

`foo` translates to `var foo`

There is a big difference between the two of those.

---

For example:

```
bar = (baz) -> 
 @bar = 5
 lemon = @bar + baz

 @foo = (bar) ->
  lemon
 return @

Bar = new bar(12)
```

Translates to:

```
var Bar, bar;

bar = function(baz) {
  var lemon;
  this.bar = 5;
  lemon = this.bar + baz;
  this.foo = function(bar) {
    return lemon;
  };
  return this;
};

Bar = new bar(12);
```

See fiddle demo of generated code: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/rXWw2/

[Here is a link showing you the CoffeeScript and it's generated code](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3abar%20%3D%20%28baz%29%20-%3E%20%0A%20%40bar%20%3D%205%0A%20lemon%20%3D%20%40bar%20%2B%20baz%0A%0A%20%40foo%20%3D%20%28bar%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20lemon%0A%20return%20%40%0A%0ABar%20%3D%20new%20bar%2812%29)

Comment: I guess I don't understand what "this" is in the context of CoffeeScript. It isn't "window"?

Comment: @AKWF it all depends on the context. see the example that I just added.

Comment: I guess you should learn javascript before starting coffeescript, you will have a hard time with coffeescript if you don't ;)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add something that seems important to understanding why the initial
    @foo = () -> "abc"
doesn't add to the global window object.

Coffeescript wraps - once compiled, it wraps all contents of every .coffee-file into a surrounding anonymous function that is immediately executed.
Thusly, and explicitely for that reason, the global namespace is not polluted, thereby implicitely protecting the dev from creating "evil" globals.

So, your foo becomes a member function of an anonymous wrapper function - how seriously useless *gg* ...

I guess what you want anyway is your global config object or something, to which you simply add your definitions --- you surely didn't mean to really create globals just for quick and easy access now, did you?? :)